# Check if the variable is an integer or not in C++

Tags: c++, function, validation, integer, cin

there is an

```
int a;
```

User enters a value but this value should be passed to a function that validates if the user entered an integer or if the user entered something else, without program crash.

```
cin.good()
```

will **NOT** work since it is the variable 'a' which I am passing to the function. Validation should take place inside the function

```
bool validateInteger(int a)
{
???
}
```

How to check if a is an integer or not?

Comment: An `int` is **always** an integer.  If it isn't an integer, you can't get that far.

Comment: You probably mean to check if a character string contains a valid representation of an integer ? `sscanf` can do it.

Comment: What you seek to do is impossible with the way C++ works.

Answer (score 4):

If you can pass it into your function, it is an `int` (or has an implicit conversion to `int`). Otherwise it wouldn't have compiled. So there's no need for validation.